# Do Hypothetical Syllogism and Contraction Come as Sufficient for Self-Distribution?

Tags: propositional-calculus

If we have the following axioms (under detachment)

```
 1. CCpqCCqrCpr-hypothetical syllogism
 2. CCpCpqCpq-contraction
 3. CpCqp-recursive variable prefixing
```

Then we can deduce

```
 4. CCpCqrCCpqCpr-distribution
```

3. and 4. suffice for The Deduction Metatheorem.  I've run the prover Prover9 and the model checker Mace 4 for some 3600 seconds to try and see if 1. and 2. would suffice for distribution or not, but come up with nothing.  I suspect that you can't prove distribution from {hypothetical syllogism, contraction}, but if so, what would model satisfies 1. and 2., but not 4.?  If not, how do we prove distribution from {hypothetical syllogism, contraction}?

Answer (score 1):

I think (I do remember that my program could prove it)

you can proof self- distribution  ( CCpCqrCCpqCpr) from

- one of prefixing  (CCpqCCrpCrq) and suffixing (CCpqCCqrCpr)
- one of permutation(CCpCqrCqCpr) and assertion (CpCCpqq)
  and
- contraction ( CCpCpqCpq )

maybe you also need self implication ( Cpp ) but I doubt that

so in your case i think you need to add permutation(CCpCqrCqCpr) or assertion (CpCCpqq)
let me know what happens if you add one of these two.
if needed also add Cpp

good luck

Comment: Prefixing and assertion alone allow you to prove self-implication.

Comment: You don't need Cpp.  Your assertion that {CCpqCCrpCrq, CCpCqrCqCpr, CCpCpqCpq}, {CCpqCCrpCrq, CpCCpqq, CCpCpqCpq}, {CCpqCCrpCrq, CCpCqrCqCpr, CCpCpqCpq} and {CCpqCCrpCrq, CpCCpqq, CCpCpqCpq} all have CCpCqrCCpqCpr as a theorem is correct.  But, not all of them have Cpp as a theorem.